# Fully General Relativistic treatment of Galaxy Rotation Curve

Tags: general-relativity, orbital-motion, dark-matter, geodesics, galaxy-rotation-curve

Over the years I have seen several approaches to this problem in the GR context: perturbations around a flat-spacetime, cancelation by hand of $\mathcal{O}(\partial_{\mu}\textbf{g}^{2})$ terms on the field equations (with $\textbf{g}$ the metric tensor)...but, has anyone attempted to solve the problem in a fully general relativistic way?
By that, I mean a scheme like this:

Step 1: Proposal of a metric (for instance, Weyl axially symmetric disk),

Step 2: Proposal of an energy-momentum tensor (of ordinary matter only), and insertion in the Einstein field equations,

Step 3: Solution of the arising set of differential equations,

Step 4: A definition for the "circular velocity": for instance, from the equations for the geodesic curve:

\begin{equation*}
v_{c}^{2} = r\frac{d^{2}r}{d\tau^{2}} = -r\Gamma^{r}_{\ \alpha\beta}\frac{dx^{\alpha}}{d\tau}\frac{dx^{\beta}}{d\tau},
\end{equation*}

with $\tau$ proper time. (I know, this is a too naïve proposal!),

Step 5: Comparison with observations.

I am well aware of the order-of-magnitude $GMc^{-2}R^{-1}$ estimation which is frequently invoked to dismiss the need for GR but, are there people who have done this? If so, have the results confirmed that dark matter is still needed?

Comment: Doing this in full GR would be extremely rough, and if you wanted to see if the GR corrections are significant, an easier route would likely be doing numerical simulations in a PPN framework.

Comment: *Solution of the arising set of differential equations*  Unfortunately most equations will not be solvable in a strict analytical sense and require either simplifications (e.g. dropping higher order terms) or perturbation approaches.  This doesn't seem to be what you want, and if you do want rigor in solutions I suspect you'd be dissappointed.

Comment: Numerical n-body simulations can be General Relativistic and reproduce the observed rotation curves, but indeed that's not an analytic treatment as suggested here.

Comment: What extra *physical* information are you expecting to get from an exact analytical solution that you can't get from a controlled approximation or a numerical simulation? Of course it's *nice* to have exact solutions if possible, but in this case there is no realistic path I know of to obtaining such a solution, and also (I would argue) such a solution is not necessary to learn about the physics you are interested in.

Comment: Forgive my lack of details on point 3: by solution I meant either analytic or numerical. Step 1-3 are the usual procedure in simple neutron stars for example, where you obtain tabulated expressions for metric functions and the density profile. Still, I would highly appreciate if you could point me to existent papers where fully relativistic numerical simulations, assuming no dark matter, are carried. In principle, I would expect that full terms and not only perturbations would be responsible for the "missing" matter.

Comment: As an academic argument one might bring forward that the post-Newtonian (or indeed Newtonian) approximation of General Relativity is entirely adequate here, then use that calculation and claim it as being the General Relativistic result... in a sense, this might be why there might not even be a direct calculation using General Relativity - the various simplifications are adequate and could thus be considered part of the proper "General Relativistic" treatment as well?